# How do I make a web form select look normal with Android 3.1 on a tablet?

Tags: android, html, forms, web, html-select

I am building a web site that needs to work on computers as well as tablets and I have found that if you have a web form with select tags in it, when you view it with a tablet running android 3.1 the select options are shown in a modal window at the bottom of the page.

when you select options using this method, it is no longer the select option changing in the DOM and you cannot react to changes.  Is there a way to disable this so that a dropdown is a dropdown and looks and reacts as it would on a desktop?

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help. (Google has yet to yield any results for me)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)? It basically implements jQuery for mobile devices. I found that there's a way to build [Select Menus](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html) right there.

Comment: I have looked at jQuery Mobile, however I am building a web-app that will be cross-compatible with just about everything (pc and tablet) and I have created an android app using a webview, however, it is using the default behaviour on select menus, and I don't want to have to develope an entire app just for android